# Syntax error missing operator in query expression '[void]'='

Tags: vb.net

Please help me - I am working in project where i want to update data from directly datagridview but when I try the following code, I got an error

> Syntax error missing operator in query expression '[void]'='

and the update is not working:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To jamadata.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1
        query = "update rojmel set [jrs]='" & jamadata.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "',[note]='" & jamadata.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "' Where [void]= " & jamadata.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & ""

    Next
    If (mydb.Exacutemyoledb(query)) Then
        MsgBox(" data updated")
    End If
```

I am using this class for update query

[image]

Code:

```
 Shared Function Exacutemyoledb(ByVal sql As String) As Boolean
    Try
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

This is my datatype

Comment: It's always infuriating when people post questions about errors in SQL code and don't bother to show the SQL code, which generally means that they haven't bothered to look at it themselves either. The VB code that constructs the SQL code is not the SQL code. Look at the actual SQL code. If you still can't fix it, show us the actual SQL code.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code in the first place. You should always be using parameters. If you data access class doesn't enable you to do that then it's garbage and you should either fix it or throw it away.

Comment: There is no column named `void` in the database.

Comment: The string for the query ends up with *only* the last row, so the query is only run for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to see that you are separating your UI code from your data access code but you don't want sql statements and parameters in you UI code.

I am assuming that `jamadata` is a `DataTable` probably bound to a DataGridView. It is rather odd that the ID would be in column 3 but that would depend on your original select. We just need to send the data off to the `mydb` class function. A `List(Of T)` is convenient because we don't need to know the size. We just loop through all the rows and add the values we need for parameters.

If all you plan to do is show a message if there is an error, then let the error bubble up to the user interface code and show your message there.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lstJRS As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim lstNote As New List(Of String)
    Dim lstID As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each row As DataRow In jamadata.Rows
        lstJRS.Add(CInt(row(0)))
        lstNote.Add(row(2).ToString)
        lstID.Add(CInt(row(3)))
    Next
    Try
        If (mydb.Exacutemyoledb(lstJRS, lstNote, lstID)) Then
            MsgBox(" data updated")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now to the class code. It looks like you have declared `cmd` and `cn` at the class level. This is not good since both of these objects need to be disposed after use. You need to create and dispose in the method where they are used. It is probably convenient to have the connection string as a class level variable.

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that objects are closed and disposed even it there is an error. Both the connection and command are included in the block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the Using.

We add the parameters to the parameters collection once outside the loop. It is only the value of the parameters that change in the loop. Access ignores the names of the parameters; we use them just for readability. The order that they appear in the sql string must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection.

```
Private Shared ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Shared Function Exacutemyoledb(JRS As List(Of Integer), Notes As List(Of String), IDs As List(Of Integer)) As Boolean
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update rojmel Set jrs = @JRS, note = @Note Where ID = @ID;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@JRS", OleDbType.Integer)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Note", OleDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer)
        cn.Open()
        For i = 0 To JRS.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters("@JRS").Value = JRS(i)
            cmd.Parameters("@Note").Value = Notes(i)
            cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = IDs(i)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
    Return True
End Function
```